# What is the reason of showing \t\n as node?

Tags: java, html-parsing, w3c

Let we parse well formatted HTML.

Let there is `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLLIElement` with some child nodes.

Why `\t\n` symbols become separate node?

Image for example. First two lines - `<div/>` and text inside. Second two lines - node `Text` (there is no exectly such tag) with tabs and endline symbol.

[image: Image shows normal node <code>div</code> and just text with <code>\n\t</code>]

Comment: Because those characters are in the HTML source, so why wouldn't they be in the parsed data? Even pure whitespace like that can be significant, so the parser cannot eliminate them.

Comment: But, they don't represent any tags. They don't influence to content in browser.

Comment: Spaces might influence the content in browser, e.g. if CSS [`white-space: pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) is in effect.

Answer (score 2):

whitespaces are still content, so naturally, they can be processed just as like alphanumeric (or other) characters, tags and so on